# How to change no_create: False in odoo

Tags: inheritance, odoo

My module is inherit in "sale.order".  Field payment_term_id is:

```
options="{'no_create': True}"
```

in core. 
How to change no_create:False in inherit module.
I'm try: but it's not working.

```
<record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//sheet/group/group/field[@name='payment_term_id']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="attrs">{'no_create': false}</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the attribute `options`:

```xml
<record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//sheet/group/group/field[@name='payment_term_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="options" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```